# Hide bootstrap row column based on the data

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, kendo-grid

I am running one jquery kendo grid row template where i am showing some content with images.Below is the code :

```html
 <table id="grid" style="width:100%">
                <colgroup>
                    <col class="photo" />
                    <col class="details" />
                    <col />
                </colgroup>
                <thead style="display:none">
                    <tr>

                        <th>
                            Details
                        </th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:30%">
                     div class="row">
                            <div id="dvImage" class="col-sm-4" style="width:118px">
                                #= imagelink #
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8" style="width:400px">
                                <span class="name" style="font-size:14px; color:green">#: Link #</span>
                               
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </script>
            <style>
                .name {
                    display: block;
                    font-size: 1.3em;
                }

                .k-grid-header .k-header {
                    padding: 0px 20px;
                }

                .k-grid-content {
                    overflow-y: auto;
                }

                .k-grid tr td {
                    background: white !important;
                    border: 0 !important;
                    border-color: transparent;
                }

                .k pager-wrap {
                    border-width: 1px !important;
                    border-color: #ccc;
                }

                .k-block, .k-widget, .k-input, .k-textbox, .k-group, .k-content, .k-header, .k-filter-row > th, .k-editable-area, .k-separator, .k-colorpicker .k-i-arrow-s, .k-textbox > input, .k-autocomplete, .k-dropdown-wrap, .k-toolbar, .k-group-footer td, .k-grid-footer, .k-footer-template td, .k-state-default, .k-state-default .k-select, .k-state-disabled, .k-grid-header, .k-grid-header-wrap, .k-grid-header-locked, .k-grid-footer-locked, .k-grid-content-locked, .k-grid td, .k-grid td.k-state-selected, .k-grid-footer-wrap, .k-pager-wrap, .k-pager-wrap .k-link, .k-pager-refresh, .k-grouping-header, .k-grouping-header .k-group-indicator, .k-panelbar > .k-item > .k-link, .k-panel > .k-item > .k-link, .k-panelbar .k-panel, .k-panelbar .k-content, .k-treemap-tile, .k-calendar th, .k-slider-track, .k-splitbar, .k-dropzone-active, .k-tiles, .k-toolbar, .k-tooltip, .k-button-group .k-tool, .k-upload-files {
                    border-color: transparent;
                }
                .col-md-2 {
                    width:118px
                }
                .col-md-3 {
                    width:25%
                }

            </style>
```

In the above code i have Image and description which i am showing but for some of the rows i don't have image but still it's containing the space. So here i need that if image is null for particular row then it should hide that image column. I tried like this but did not get any luck.
Below is the code:

```html
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            autoBind: false,
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "/Home/GetSearchData",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { searchTerm: $('[id*=hdnHomeSearch]').val() }
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                        return kendo.stringify(data);
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 10,
                schema: {
                    parse: function (data) {
                        debugger;
                        var items = [];
                        var chkCorrectVal = 0;
                        var context = $('#dvImage');
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
                            if (data.data[i].CorrectValue != null && data.data[i].SearchValue != null) {
                                $("#spnSR")[i].innerHTML = "<b>" + "Get results for this text: " + "</b>" + data.data[i].CorrectValue;
                                $("#spnSV")[i].innerHTML = "<b>" + "Searched for this text: " + "</b>" + data.data[i].SearchValue;
                                chkCorrectVal = 1;
                            }
                            else {
                                if (chkCorrectVal == 0) {
                                    $("#spnSR").hide();
                                    $("#spnSV").hide();
                                }
                            }
                            if (!data.data[i].imagelink) {
                                var getContext = $(context[i]);
                                data.data[i].imagelink = "";
                                $(context[i]).addClass('hidden');
                            }
                           
                        }
                        var product = {
                            
                            data: data.data,
                            total: data.total
                        };
                        items.push(product);
                        return (items[0].data);
                    },

                }
            },
            dataBound: function () {
                DisplayNoResultFound($("#grid"));
            },
            serverPaging: true,

            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: true
            },
            rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#rowTemplate").html()),
        });
    });
```

One more example i am pasting here where i am trying to get the same results and that is working fine for me.
Below is the code:

```html
           <input type="submit" id="soltitle" value="#1"/>
             
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2" id="hell1">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title"></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="timeline1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb11" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title"></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="timeline1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x160" alt="Thumb11" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       
        $('#soltitle').click(function () {
          
            $('#hell1')
                // Find parent with the class that starts with "col-md"
                // Change class to "col-md-3"
                .closest('[class^="col-md"]')
                    .toggleClass('col-md-2 col-md-2 hidden')
                // Find siblings of parent with similar class criteria
                // - if all siblings are the same, you can use ".siblings()"
                // Change class to "col-md-2"
                //.siblings('[class^="col-md"]')
                //    .removeClass('col-md-3')
                //    .addClass('col-md-2');
        });
    });
</script>
```

in this example i am hiding first column in button click event and that is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you toggle the class for all rows where the image does not exist. Each time you toggle those and toggle again, the second toggle negates the first one. If the rows where the if is evaluated to true is pair, then the last toggle was a negation.

It is not clear whether you need to hide the whole column if you find one such row, or you need to hide the column only for the affected row specifically. Also, your if is incorrect.

If you want to hide the whole column if at least such a row exists, then this might be the solution:

```
var shouldShow = true;
 for (var i = 0; shouldShow && (i < data.data.length); i++) {

                            if (!data.data[i].imagelink) {
                                $(".imageClass").addClass('hidden');
                                shouldShow = false;
                            }

                        }
```

If you want to do it only for the affected row, then something like this might help you:

```
 var context = $(".imageClass");
 for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {

                            if (!data.data[i].imagelink) {
                                $(context[i]).addClass('hidden');
                            }

                        }
```

The code assumes you have a single column having imageClass.

EDIT

It turned out that the .hidden class was not defined. There are two possible solutions, you can choose either of them.

Solution1: replace `.addClass("hidden")` with `.hide()`

Solution2: Add the following rule to the CSS code: `.hidden {display: none;}`

Comment: Hey Lajos thanks for quick reply the second suggestion i tried because i need that if particular row contain image then it should show but it's not working. still contains space and showing null. i tried with addClass instead of toggleClass but no luck. Thanks

Comment: @Vikash, sorry, I forgot to change toggleClass to addClass in the second example. I have edited my answer, please test it again.

Comment: Lajos i think you did not read my comment completely there i mentioned clearly that i have tested this with addClass also but did not get any luck.

Comment: Oh, sorry. addClass was an improvement anyway. Can you tell me how is it not working? Did you debug the code using your browser console?

Comment: I debugged it and traced it. process is going inside this if condition but not making hidden. I tried with one another example without this grid for that i used one table there i am hiding particular row for that it's working fine. the same example i used with this but for this also it's not working. something wrong here because we are passing id name with loop data, may be due to this it's not working.

Comment: I would like to see your html and css as well.

Comment: Lajos, as per your request i edited my question above where i put complete code of html kendo grid row template with css and jquery kendo grid code.

Comment: in the above code i also added one more example that is working fine. The difference is only that here id we are setting with loop variable in grid. Please check it. Thanks

Comment: imageClass ! means i did not understand what you are trying to say? can you elaborate more?

Comment: Hey Lajos, sorry before i did not see the previous inserted code, yes i used image class directly to use addClass hidden but in the edited example now i am using dvImage id for that div which i have to make hidden. You can check in the above code, div id i am parsing in one context variable and that context variable using to make hidden.

Comment: @Vikash, I do not find the rules for the hidden css class. Can you show me what CSS did you use for that class?

Comment: as you can see first in the html code i provided id for div as dvImage. Then you can see in jquery code i have used this code var context = $('#dvImage'); Then in the if condition used hidden class if (!data.data[i].imagelink) {
                               
                                $(context[i]).addClass('hidden');
                            } Now you have any doubt can ask to me.

Comment: @Vikash, again. Where is the rule for the hidden class defined? You try to hide an html element by adding the hidden class. Yet I do not see something like .hidden {display: none} in your css

Comment: Do we need a rule to hidden the div? directly can't hidden the div in jquery code? if i am doing something wrong please assist me.

Comment: @Vikash, you can hide something with jquery if you call the .hide() function of the jquery object, however, if you add a hidden class, then you need to defined that class in your CSS code. So you either call $(context[i]).hide() or leave the Javascript code as it is.

Comment: Lajos, I tried with addClass and define that css display:none in css and tried with addCss and removeClass col-sm-4 also but none of these worked for me.

Comment: Now i am completely sure that this id is not identify by jquery. For testing purpose i tried to write some text in div but it was not writing. Can anyone help me to achieve this?